# Calling Delphi code from C# program

Tags: c#, delphi

I have dozens of Delphi (version 10.2.2 Tokyo) functions that I would like to be accessible from a C# MVC web project. These functions are mainly report queries that take a bunch of input parameters and output an array (or list) of records (or objects) as result.

I have full control on both code bases, Delphi and C#. What would be the best architecture in this scenario to share the code base? DLL would be an option but I don't like the low level details that comes with it, what are better options?

Obs: the functions must be available to be called from both, Delphi and C# code.

Comment: Is [Embarcadero Prism](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/prism) a viable option for you? As I understand it, you should be able to use this to recompile your Delphi code to .NET assemblies, making it much easier to access them from C#.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, I'll take a look. But I will probably need to make these functions accessible to be called from both C# and Delphi, I'll update the question with this information.

Comment: When you say dozens, do you mean 24.... or more like 144 ?

Comment: More like 144..

Answer (score 8):

At a previous job, we did exactly what you're describing: An ASP.NET webserver that handed off a lot of the heavy lifting to a native Delphi codebase.  We had two methods we used.

The first was to put a lot of it in a DLL, which was registered with Windows as an out-of-process COM server.  This avoids a lot of the messy low-level hackery with P/Invoke, but gives you a bunch of messy low-level hackery on the Delphi side, so it's kind of a tradeoff there.

The second method was to build the Delphi code as a REST server and have the C# code make webservice calls to it.  This provides a much cleaner interface, at the cost of a bit of performance.  We used this method for heavy database processing, the sort of stuff where the overhead of an HTTP call wouldn't really be noticed, and the COM DLL for tighter stuff where efficiency mattered more.

Having native code interoperate with managed code is going to be messy one way or another; it really comes down to engineering tradeoffs and which variety of mess ends up working best for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Another language-agnostic solution could be to give your Delphi code a command line interface, pass the parameters by some input file (plain text, XML or JSON), and return the query results in some output file (plain text, XML or JSON, whatever you prefer).  Calling those command line tool and processing the input and output then can be done in almost any programming language you like.

Of course, that is only a useful solution if each query can be a short living process, with no need to reuse something like a long living database connection.

We used such a file based interoperation in the past to connect old 16 bit C++ code with newer C# code. It wasn't actually too hard to create a robust solution, and the performance impact of using files turned out to be negligible for our use cases (but YMMV).

Comment: I've also used a similar approach to integrate a Delphi and a C# codebase, and I'll double Doc's. The approach on this answer can work very well if you don't have some exotic needs over your database. ( +1 from me, @DocBrown)